# problem with connecting multiple clients to a server

Tags: java, server, client

hey I'm writing a simple code with a server socket and multiple clients which the server gets every client's username and stores them in a hashmap.the server accepts a socket client and the client enters the username but again the server accept the same socket client and it wants its username and the code stops here.i want it to work for multiple clients not just one.

server class:

```
public class Server implements Serializable{

    // [..]

    public void serverConnect() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        listener = new ServerSocket(9090);

        System.out.println("Server is running...");
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.println("Waiting ...");
            socket=listener.accept();
            for (Socket socket:socketList.keySet())
            {
                if (this.socket==socket)
                {
                checkSocket=false;
                }
            }
            if (checkSocket)
            {
            socketList.put(socket,socketNumber);
            System.out.println("Client is connected");
            inputReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(inputReader);

            user = reader.readLine();
            Server.userList.add(user);
            socketNumber++;
            }
            checkSocket=true;
            }
    }
}
```

client class:

```
public class Client {
    public Client() {
    }

    public void clientConnect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        System.out.println("enter your username");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        String msg = scanner.nextLine();
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 9090);
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
            writer.println(msg);
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know who will go through your entire code post, especially since you have not isolated the problem for us, but I will suggest that you not recreate your streams within the client's `while (true)` loop. Create them once before and then use them in the loop.

Comment: Also, doesn't your server need to create a new thread for each client that it accepts?

Comment: just don't care about serverthread and clientthread they are for another purpose,but i mean the server accepts a socket client and the client enters the username but again the server accept the same socket client and it wants its username and the code stops here.i want it to work for multiple clients not just one.

Answer (score 0):

In principle you have the workings of single thread server (which means it can accept only one client connection at a time). The main issue is that you have over-complicated how you receive a connection.

You can simplify your current code by dealing by moving the client connection socket and readers into the local scope and dealing with the socket directly.

```java
    public void serverConnect() throws IOException {
        listener = new ServerSocket(9090);
        System.out.println("Server is running...");

        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting ...");
            Socket socket = listener.accept();

            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
                String user = reader.readLine();
                Server.userList.add(user);
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            } finally {
                socket.close();  
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see you don't need to keep hold of the socket beyond reading the value sent. If you are only expecting the one line of data from the client, you should also close the socket otherwise the client can hold the server hostage by not sending any data until the socket timeout is reached.

Further to this you also want to wrap the code inside the while loop with a try/catch block to prevent an exception terminating the server.

As I mentioned in the opening paragraph this code works as a single threaded server and it can only respond to a single request at a time. If you want to accept and process multiple requests you will need to spawn a new thread to handle the response. I would recommend constructing your code as below but for the sake of brevity you could do something like below:

```java
    public void serverConnect() throws IOException {
        int MAX_WORKERS = 100;
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_WORKERS);
        ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(9090);

        System.out.println("Server is running...");
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("Waiting ...");
            Socket socket = listener.accept();

            service.submit(() -> {
                System.out.println("Client is connected");
                try {
                    try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()))) {
                        String user = reader.readLine();
                        Server.userList.add(user);
                    } finally {
                        socket.close();
                    }
                } catch (Throwable ignore) {
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

So all that is happening above is that we are creating a thread pool of 100 threads using the `ExecutorService`. This means in theory we can accept 100 concurrent connections.

When a connection is accepted, we submit the socket and worker code to a thread which means that the main thread can return to listening for a new connections.

Comment: It doesn’t work.Clients can’t connect to server even the first one.

Comment: 1. Try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost in your Client code.

Comment: No difference. -

Comment: Can you add the output of your Server and Client code to your question?